# React mapping array from Express API

Tags: json, reactjs, express

I am having trouble mapping the data from my Express API in React.

I have mapped data before from my Express API services without issues but I think the data is being displayed in a 2d array or something. I tried accessing it like a 2d array [0][0] but that didnt work. I can see the data in Google Chrome in my array.

I got the data in JSON format below from Postman.

Thank you very much for the help.

React Class:

```
class ScoreData extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedWeek: 1,
        selectedSeason: 2015,
        scoreData:[]            
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/users/2015/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(dataArray => this.setState({scoreData: dataArray.data})); 

}
```

Map function:

```
return (
<div>
    <h1>NFL Score Data</h1>

    <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>

    {this.state.scoreData[0].map(currentScoreData=>
        <div >
            <p>{currentScoreData.PK_GameID}</p>
            <p>{currentScoreData.homeTeamPoints}</p>
            <p>{currentScoreData.awayTeamPoints}</p>
            <p>{currentScoreData.gameDate}</p>
            <p>{currentScoreData.FK_AwayTeamID}</p>
            <p>{currentScoreData.FK_HomeTeamID}</p>
        </div>
    )}
```

{

```
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1591,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 31,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 3
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1591,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 17,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 31,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 3
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1591,
                "homeTeamPoints": 8,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 31,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 3
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1591,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 31,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 3
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1595,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 6,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 4
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1595,
                "homeTeamPoints": 9,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 6,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 4
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1595,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 6,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 4
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1595,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 6,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 4
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1589,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 27,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 5
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1589,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 27,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 5
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1589,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 27,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 5
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1589,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 27,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 5
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1602,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 2,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 8
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1602,
                "homeTeamPoints": 14,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 2,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 8
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1602,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 2,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 8
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1602,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 2,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 8
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1594,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 25,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 9
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1594,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 6,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 25,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 9
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1594,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 21,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 25,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 9
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1594,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 21,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 25,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 9
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1590,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 28,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1590,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 28,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1590,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 28,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1590,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 28,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1603,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 14,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 23,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1603,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 23,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1603,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 23,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1603,
                "homeTeamPoints": 17,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 23,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 10
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1593,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 1,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 14
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1593,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 1,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 14
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1593,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 1,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 14
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1593,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 1,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 14
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1604,
                "homeTeamPoints": 6,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-19T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 3,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 16
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1604,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-19T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 3,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 16
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1604,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-19T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 3,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 16
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1604,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-19T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 3,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 16
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1601,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 7,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 17
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1601,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 3,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 7,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 17
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1601,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 7,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 17
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1601,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 7,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 17
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1599,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 6,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 21,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 18
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1599,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 6,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 21,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 18
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1599,
                "homeTeamPoints": 9,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 21,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 18
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1599,
                "homeTeamPoints": 6,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 21,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 18
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1592,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 11,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 19
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1592,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 11,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 19
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1592,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 11,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 19
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1592,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 11,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 19
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1596,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 12,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 22
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1596,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 6,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 12,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 22
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1596,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 12,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 22
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1596,
                "homeTeamPoints": 14,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 12,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 22
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1588,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 15,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 23
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1588,
                "homeTeamPoints": 10,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 15,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 23
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1588,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 15,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 23
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1588,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 15,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 23
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1600,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 16,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 26
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1600,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 14,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 16,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 26
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1600,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 16,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 26
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1600,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 14,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 16,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 26
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1598,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 13,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 29
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1598,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 13,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 29
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1598,
                "homeTeamPoints": 7,
                "awayTeamPoints": 14,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 13,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 29
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1598,
                "homeTeamPoints": 3,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 13,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 29
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1597,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 21,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 24,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 30
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1597,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 7,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 24,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 30
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1597,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 10,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 24,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 30
            },
            {
                "PK_GameID": 1597,
                "homeTeamPoints": 0,
                "awayTeamPoints": 0,
                "gameDate": "2015-12-13T05:00:00.000Z",
                "FK_AwayTeamID": 24,
                "FK_HomeTeamID": 30
            }
        ],
        {
            "fieldCount": 0,
            "affectedRows": 0,
            "insertId": 0,
            "serverStatus": 2,
            "warningCount": 0,
            "message": "",
            "protocol41": true,
            "changedRows": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so, what's the problem you are facing? what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have is correct for the most part it looks like you only need to add the nested array to the default value:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         selectedWeek: 1,
         selectedSeason: 2015,
         scoreData:[ [] ], // <--- this right here
    };
}
```

Or alternatively set `scoreData` to the nested array

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked right away. Another thing I have learned :)

mapped it with:
    {this.state.scoreData[0].map(currentScoreData=>